# Is there a more effient way for interp2 MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Using MATLAB I have a table of, let's say, x(size(100x1)), y(size(100x1)) and z(size(100x100)) and I use:

```
 z1 = interp2(x,y,z,x1,x2)
```

to find a value that i need for later calculation. Is there a more efficient/quicker way to implement this?  I tried unsuccessfully to implement it with scatteredInterpolant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your question. Are you referring to a better call instead of `interp2`, or something about the tuple `(x1, x2)`?

If you're referring to `interp2`, as you can see by typing in matlab `>>> type interp2` that ultimately matlab calls `griddedInterpolant`. I can't find the code to this built-in call online, but [this](http://wefixbugs.com/blog/How-to-make-my-GPU-interpolation-code-for-MATLAB-faster-660218.html#.VELxTt__5k8) link indicates that `interp2` is fast. `interpn` is overloaded for GPUs, perhaps `interp2` is now or might be in the future.

The `interp2` function itself is handy, in my opinion. I've used `interp` extensively. There are different types of polynomial interpolation and some metrics for extrapolation.

Without a better definition of your question I'll have to leave it at that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey there.I tried both with interp2,griddenInterpolant and scatteredInterpolant. I post the resutls of the computational time:  interp2:5.18sec , griddenInterpolant:4.8sec,  scatteredInterpolant: 10,1sec

Comment: `interp2` performs many checks before calling `griddedInterpolant`, which is the reason for its ~400ms slower performance. `interp2` is a wrapper for `griddedInterpolant`.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on your data and points where you want to interpolate. If the data are in an aligned grid, it is possible to use griddata. 
If the data are scattered and the points to interpolate at are in a grid, scatteredInterpolant should be ok:

```
%% // scattered data, interpolate at grid
% // random coordinate pair
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
% // function to interpolate
func = sin(x.*y);
% // interp function
F = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,func);
% // grid to interpolate at:
[ix iy] = ndgrid(0:.01:1);
ifunc = F(ix, iy);
% // plot
mesh(ix, iy, ifunc); 

%% // grid data, scattered interpolation
[x y] = ndgrid(1:100);  % // data coordinates
func = sin(x.*y);       % // create some data
ix = rand(100,1)*100;   % // interpolation points
iy = rand(100,1)*100;
ifunc = griddata(x,y,func,ix,iy);   % // interpolate
plot3(ix, iy, ifunc, 'o');  % // plot
```

If you need scattered-scattered interpolation...
I had the same problem with matlab before, I ended up doing a more complicated solution, as matlab function were not efficient at all.